# LibGDX json storage for game items

Tags: json, libgdx, filehandle

I have a class named item in which I have more fields of ints and floats for attributes like damage, level requirement and other stuff. I wanted to keep some predefined items in a json file and when I need a new item with that set of attributes to take it out with the name from json file. Let's say I want a sword and a bow:

```
//json example file -- this isn't a proper file 
//this is a preview of what I would like
{
godly_sword {damage: 45, level: 10},
normal_bow {damage: 4, level: 3}
}
```

I want to be able to take these from a json by their name and create a new object with those attributes like this:

```
//Creating a new item which has a preset of attributes assigned to the name godly_sword
Item weapon = json.fromJson(Item.class, "godly_sword");
```

I tried playing with this in different ways but all I could do is load only one preset:

```
//Proper json file
{
class: game.Item,
damage: 45,
level: 10
}
```

This works but it isn't much of a help, because I don't want to create a json file for every item I predefined. Any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Keys should be in quotes.

```
{
"godly_sword" {"damage": 45, "level": 10},
"normal_bow" {"damage": 4, "level": 3}
}
```

You could also consider defining the weapons in an array, which you do using square brackets [].

Take a look at this tutorial on [Parsing JSON in libGdx](http://jackyjjc.com/2013/10/07/parsing-json-in-libgdx-tutorial/). If you're  new to JSON, it explains things in much clearer terms than the libGdx wiki.

Comment: Using arrays would mean I would have to hash some keys with strings inside code so I can get the weapon by it's name but I would like to avoid this. That's why I wanted to take the corresponding item by it's name defined in the json file. The example uses arrays and then takes the monster by an id. I wanted to avoid hashing keys inside code and instead make some kind of custom getter: Item myItem = json.fromJson (Item.class, "name of item", "path of json file");